# Is there any way to combine to internet connections

Tags: networking

I have two network interfaces which are a wireless and a mobile broadband. They have different networks or service provider. I plan to combine them for faster upload and download speeds. Is there  any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to search for the term "bonding". This will allow you to use two connections in parallel. You will not be able to use the full bandwith of all connections with a single transfer, but if you have multiple transfers they can be routed through both connections for load balancing.

This seems like a pretty solid guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debian-ubuntu-teaming-aggregating-multiple-network-connections.html

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with mobile broadband, but I may be incorrect.